# Check related object is null in Ember and Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

When related data is serialized in a 0-1 relationship, everything works fine.

```
"lesson": {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "foo",
  "user_completion": {
    "id": 1,
    "percent": 30
  },
  "is_available": true
}
```

However, when the related model hasn't been created yet, the web service returns null for that relation.

```
"lesson": {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "foo",
  "user_completion": null,
  "is_available": false
}
```

It appears that when the ember model is instantiated with this data, the user_completion becomes a **PromiseObject** instead.

1. Should my web service be returning null for this relation when no related one-to-zero-or-one record exists?
2. Is it right for Ember Data to have put a promise object on this property of the model, even though it can never resolve to anything? Am I missing something important?
3. What should I be doing in cases where I need to check for the existence of related data, as in the following example?

   ```
   model.filter(function(item) {
     return item.get('is_available') || item.get('user_completion') !== null;
   });
   ```

   Do I really just need to check if user_completion is a PromiseObject? That seems a little odd, and I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more investigation, it turns out that if you had a relationship defined as async, it will *always* return a promise, whether you inline the relationship or not.

Change

```
user_completion: DS.belongsTo('user_completion', {async: true})
```

to

```
user_completion: DS.belongsTo('user_completion', {async: false})
```

and everything works as expected; Ember returns `null` for an empty relationship.

For what it's worth, it looks like `async: true` [may become the default in future](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1443#issuecomment-26607013).